# Windows Clipboard function crashing when assigning null terminator

Tags: c++, c, winapi, clipboard

In my function to copy text I do the following:

```
    // Allocate a global memory object for the text. 
    hglbCopy = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, 
        ((text.length() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR))); 

    if (hglbCopy == NULL) 
    { 
        CloseClipboard(); 
        return; 
    } 

    // Lock the handle and copy the text to the buffer. 
    lptstrCopy = (LPWSTR)GlobalLock(hglbCopy); 
    memcpy(lptstrCopy, text.c_str(), 
        (text.length() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR) ); 
    lptstrCopy[(text.length() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)] = (WCHAR) 0;    // null character CRASHES HERE
    GlobalUnlock(hglbCopy);
```

When I copy a large chunk of text, it crashes when assigning the null terminator. Is there something wrong with my math in calculating how much memory to allocate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to assign the null terminator yourself.

If you want to do it yourself do it like this:

```
((WCHAR*)lptstrCopy)[text.length()]=L'\0';
```

Comment: In other words, `lptstrCopy` is an array of `WCHAR` and needs to be indexed so. You are indexing it as an array of `char`.

Comment: You are still overflowing the buffer by 1 `WCHAR`. Get rid of the `+1`. Actually, the entire line is not necessary at all. The null terminator was copied as part of the memcpy.

Comment: This answer is misleading, correct is what Raymond writes (and his comment should probably be an answer).